# Как использовать docker-toolbox с vs2017

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Я использую VS2017 Enterprise version 15.8.1
Установил docker-toolbox(полноценный не смог поставить так как у меня windows10 home)
При попытке запустить приложение(любое, просто стартовое WebAPI к примеру) - выдает ошибку - error CTC1003: Visual Studio container tools require Docker to be running. (на пустом проекте).

Comment: Докер на домашней Винде не работает, поэтому, думаю, никак без профессиональной не обойтись.

Comment: docker-toolbox работает. Разве его нельзя использовать? Я разницы конечно не знаю, но установить и запустить hello-world у меня получилось. То есть сам докер очевидно работает. Не работает у меня VS2017 в связке c docker-toolbox